# Moved files from shared folder and they disappeared

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I just suffered a catastrophic data loss and I'm hoping that someone here knows how to recover lost Google docs.

I have two Google accounts: one personal, one for work. I created several files for a work-related report on my personal account, then shared the folder with my work account. Using my work account, I then moved the files to a parent directory. I received a pop-up that said that this might "cause some users to lose access." I naively clicked OK.

The result seems to be that the files no longer exist on either account.

Ctrl + Z yields a "Nothing to Undo" message.

I realize now what I *should have* done, but I really need to recover these files. Can anyone here help?

Comment: I came here because I want to intentionally make a file "unorganized"... in order to archive it (not see it in my folders), but not delete it as it was shared in a comment in order to explain something.

Answer (score 5):

After a few harrowing minutes, I managed to solve this problem. I'll preserve the thread in case anyone else screws themselves in such a manner.

1. Using the drive which created the file, click on the information icon in the upper right.
2. Under the "activity" tab, you should see a list of actions with the accompanying files.
3. Click the files/folders to open.
4. Click the dropdown menu on the title bar and select "Add to My Drive."

Voila. You're unscrewed.

Answer (score 4):

Your files are orphaned. In the Drive search field, type:
`is:unorganized owner:me`

Or click the magic blue button on [this support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339).

Comment: In a shared folder, the owner might be someone else, so make sure to have everyone involved do this.

Comment: (For some reason,` is:unorganized owner:{other person}` didn’t work for me.)

Answer (score 0):

`tldr`: Refresh the page on **each** sub-folder (of the shared folder) that seems to be empty in your destination account.

---

Explanation:
Not 100% sure if my setup/condition is exactly as the OP's. My setup was:
- Destination account creates shared folder `shared`
- Source account moves all My-Drive files and folder into `shared`
=> In the destination account the `shared` folder contains some files, some folders. Most of the subfolders were empty, no matter whether I accessed them the first time.